# Best way to graph an ETL data flow

Tags: sql-server, graph, ssis, etl

I found the following **Version 1** in one of our detailed design documents. If I were going to create it, I would have probably displayed it as shown in **Version 2**

However, I'm thinking that there probably is a more common standard way of showing the flow of data by programs acting on it and that, while I prefer version 2, it probably is unnconventional and non-standard.

In Version 1, programs are shown as boxes. In Version 2, programs are depicted as arrows indicating that they are moving data from one table to another.

Q: What is the better more accepted way? Sequence Diagrams? If Sequence Diagrams were used, I think it wouldn't show the flow of data from one table to the next as well...

**Version 1:**

[image]

**Version 2:**

[image]

Comment: IMO, 2 is simpler than 1. It makes the whole process easy to understand much faster. Is this like this - get membership data, scrub it, put revenue, expenses etc related to a membership into separate tables ?

Comment: yes. For example, Program 3 moves the data from teh GHTR_Scrubbed table into the PP_REVENUE table.

Comment: Your diagram is simple and easy to understand. I think that anyone who has a general idea of ETL can understand it immediatley. A layperson with some knowledge of computers could also figure it out easily.

Comment: ChadD, I suggest that you post these kind of questions on MS and SQL server central forums also. Should I post them there for you ?

Comment: I would be happy if you would. Thank you.

Comment: Microsoft - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c82fc590-c71c-4f39-9001-b5ab1a0ed82f/best-way-to-graphdraw-an-etl-data-flow?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: SQL server central - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1532240-364-1.aspx

Comment: one more sub forum of sql server central - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1532241-363-1.aspx